# Message Hub as event source in Serverless project doesn't create any triggers or rules

Tags: node.js, openwhisk

I'm trying to set up a Message Hub topic as an event source for the cloud function like so:

```
custom:
  org: MyOrganization
  space: dev
  mhServiceName: my-kafka-service

functions:
  main:
    handler: src/handler.main
    events:
      - message_hub:
        package: /${self:custom.org}_${self:custom.space}/Bluemix_${self:custom.mhServiceName}_Credentials-1
        topic: test_topic
```

When I deploy the service, there are no triggers or rules being created. Thus the function is not being invoked when I publish messages to the Kafka topic.

I also tried to explicitly set a trigger and rule, but that only creates a trigger of type custom, instead of type message hub. Custom triggers seem to not work in this scenario.

What am I missing?

### Update

As James pointed out, the reason the triggers and rules were not created was due to the fact, that the indentation wasn't correct.

I was still running into problems with the package not being found (see my answer to James solution) when trying to deploy the function and I've found out what the problem was there.

Turns out, you have to do two more things that are not explicitly mentioned in the documentation.

1) You have to manually create service credentials (the documentation assumes you called them `Credentials-1` so I did the same)
2) You have to bind Kafka (Message Hub, now called Event Streams) to your function in your `serverless.yml`

The resulting function definition should look like this:

```
functions:
  main:
    handler: src/handler.main
    bind:
      - service:
          name: messagehub
          instance: ${self:custom.mhServiceName}
    events:
      - message_hub:
          package: /${self:custom.org}_${self:custom.space}/Bluemix_${self:custom.mhServiceName}_Credentials-1
          topic: test_topic
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The YAML indentation on the `serverless.yml` is incorrect. This means the event properties aren't registered by the framework during deployment.

Change the `serverless.yml` file to the following format and it should work.

```
custom:
  org: MyOrganization
  space: dev
  mhServiceName: my-kafka-service

functions:
  main:
    handler: src/handler.main
    events:
      - message_hub:
          package: /${self:custom.org}_${self:custom.space}/Bluemix_${self:custom.mhServiceName}_Credentials-1
          topic: test_topic
```

Comment: Ohhh, I didn't realize indentation was two levels deep, instead of just one. Thank you for finding the problem. That was indeed the reason the framework didn't even notice the properties and skipped over the configuration. 
Now it gets to the step and tries to set up the triggers, etc. but I'm getting `POST https://eu-de.functions.cloud.ibm.com/api/v1/namespaces/MyOrganization_dev/actions/Bluemix_my-kafka-service_Credentials-1/messageHubFeed?blocking=true Returned HTTP 404 (Not Found) --> "The requested resource does not exist"` back.
Does this mean I should manually create the credentials?